# How do I interpret this Rails/PostgreSQL error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm getting the following error in Rails with PostgreSQL:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
       DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null, null, 2014-05-08 13:27:56.002747, f, null, null, f, f).
       : INSERT INTO "elements" ("updated_at") VALUES ('2014-05-08 13:27:56.002747') RETURNING "id"
```

I gather it's saying I'm attempting to insert the value of `2014-05-08 13:27:56.002747` into the `updated_at` column of a row representing one instance of `Element`. Is that correct?

This should be fine, as the value looks like a valid date/time to me — correct?

I also gather it's saying `created_at` can't be `null` but that seems crazy because doesn't every instance automatically get a `created_at` value equal to the date/time at which it was created?

And what does `RETURNING "id"` mean?

I'm happy to continue debugging my app myself, but if anyone could unpack this error message for me it would be a great headstart. (Especially as the stack trace is not making it clear where the error is being created.)

Comment: `created_at` is `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT NULL` (as you wrote in the comment to @denis), thus the `INSERT` fails since you are trying to create a row with a `NULL` value for the `created_at` column. Can you write the Ruby code which generates this error?

Comment: Sorry can't find the line yet. Most of the lines in my stacktrace points to Rails internals, and I've got a few callbacks affecting models triggering callbacks. But why do you say it's `DEFAULT NULL`?

Comment: Because from the comment you wrote I guess that in the migration you don't specify the `default` value for `created_at` column, so Rails doesn't set it so the default value is set as `NULL` in the PostgreSQL column definition. Now that I'm thinking about it, something like `t.datetime 'created_at', null: false, default: 'NOW()'` could fix the issue

Comment: `RETURNING *` is a PG feature which provides the values of the of the values of the created record; it is used by Rails in order to know which is the id of the created record.

Answer (score 1):

i also got same problem
when i check it seems i have nested transaction

if You got same problem try to find

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction
```

and remove it

because seems created_at doesn't assigned when You use transaction (maybe bug)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It says: "null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint" when you run:

```
INSERT INTO "elements" ("updated_at") VALUES ('2014-05-08 13:27:56.002747')
```

Meaning that:

- You're missing some kind of default value for the `created_at` field; or
- You should set a `created_at` manually.

Comment: Sorry but don't both parts of your answer defy Rails' defaults? The standard for all my tabled models is `t.datetime "created_at", null: false`, with Rails setting the `created_at` value automatically whenever I create a new instance.

Comment: Might be. I'm merely posting what your error says and what it means though at thte Postgres level. I don't have the beginning of a clue of what Rails does or does not in the background.

Comment: This is a difference between Rails 4 and 5, apparently, and behavior varies between SQLite and PostGres e.g. For adding timestamps to existing tables in Rails 4, it's necessary to add_timestamps (without null: false) --and *then* change_column_null for the updated_at and created_at columns. See this post for more details: https://www.viget.com/articles/adding-a-not-null-column-to-an-existing-table